# Populate dropdown on React from JSON Data WebAPI

Tags: reactjs, json, react-hooks

I have a react form that has several dropdowns and it was working, however, the WebAPI changed and now the data is being returned slightly different and now none of the dropdowns are populated.

The old JSON format was like:

```
 {
    "data":
   [{
      "id" : 1,
       "name" : "Michelle Smith",
     },
     {
       "id" : 2,
       "name" : "Jenn Arnold"
     }
   ]
}
```

the drop down binding is:

```
     const [ admins, setAdmin] = useState([]);

     useEffect(() => {
       getAdmins();
     },[]);


     //calls a JS file that connects to the API using axios
     const getAdmins = () => {
       adminGroups.GetAllAdmins()
         .then((response) => {
          setAdmins(response.data.data)
         } 
        }
    
      
       return (
        <select>
       <option>...</option>
        {admins.map(data => {
           <option
               value={admin.id}
           >
            {admins.name}
          <option>
      
    
    </select>

   )
```

The new JSON format is:

```
[{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Michelle Smith",
 },
 {
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "Jenn Arnold"
}]
```

There is no parent "data" tag in the new format, what would've caused the drop downs to stop binding with the new format? When the page loads, I can see the API being called (under the network tab) and if I go to the URL I can see data, just not in the React App. Is there another way I should be binding the dropdown?

[I'm fairly new to React and converting an Access app over to the web using React as the UI]

Answer (score 0):

If all that's changed is that the API you're using no longer wraps the array in `data` then just don't go looking for it in your `response.data.data` use,

Instead just use `response.data` like so

```
const getAdmins = () => {
  adminGroups.GetAllAdmins()
    .then((response) => {
      setAdmins(response.data)
    } 
}
```

Comment: Be sure to sus out React Query when you get the hang of this, will make life easier in the long run.

Comment: Even when I do setAdmins(response.data), I see no data in the dropdowns. What's React Query ? Do I need to change the HTML for the <select> control as well?

Comment: Then you need to verify the data coming back from response.data, otherwise set some mock data to confirm there isn't a glitch on your front end code.

Comment: If I do [ console.log("data" + response),  I see data [ object ] in the console. If I can see the API being called from the code and see the data coming back in F12. Also,  in F12 if I go to the drop down, I  don't see the values, however, I can see the amount of <option> tags as there is rows but just no data, so for example, If 10 rows come back, I see 10 <option> tags, if  5 rows come back, I see 5 <option> tags, just no data.

Comment: Do a `console.log(response[0])` to see what exactly it is, might be easier you just upload the code to a repo for me to look at, or get me on Telegram, link to me is at orelo.software under John Williamson

Answer (score 0):

I got this working, just by shutting down VS and opening it back up again. Not sure if VS had something cached  or not, but the API was returning data, just not the UI until I restarted it. Thanks all